# Determine if the sequence $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is convergent when $x_k=(2k, 1, k^{-1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> Determine if the sequence $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is convergent when $$x_k=(2, 1, k^{-1})$$

Our professor gave a hint that one should look at $||2k-a||$ and try to find a contradiction here.

So assuming that it converges to say $(a,b,c)$ we get $$||(2k,1,k^{-1})-(a,b,c)||.$$

Using the hint I found that $$||2k-a||=||(1,0,0)\cdot((2k,1,k^{-1})-(a,b,c))||.$$

From Cauchy-Schwartz it follows that $$||2k-a|| \leqslant||(1,0,0)||\ ||(2k,1,k^{-1})-(a,b,c)|| = ||(2k,1,k^{-1})-(a,b,c)||$$

Hence a contradiction since $||2k-a||$ grows without a bound, when $k \to \infty.$

So couple of questions. Firstly I'm a bit confused with the notation here, should I have $|2k-a|$ instead of $||2k-a||$? And more importantly how should I come up with the intuition to look at $||2k-1||$ or $|2k-a|$ (whichever is the right notation)? I wouldn't have probably guessed this if I was doing this on an exam...

Comment: Very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809093/determine-if-the-sequence-x-k-in-mathbbr3-is-convergent-when-x-k-2-k

Comment: Very complicated for such an easy problem $$\|(2,1,\frac{1}{k})-(2,1,0)\|=\frac{1}{k}\underset{k\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$

Comment: I finally figured out what you meant to say, but it took several re reads to realize that you weren't writing down something nonsensical. Please fix your post, including your original sequence definition and the mismatched dot product, among other errors.

Comment: Apologies for posting similar questions. However I think that the overall question is a bit different here! I’m trying to get the intuition for these not the solution.

Comment: I think that your question is causing confusion since in the title you are referring to $(2,1, k^{-1})$, but then you write $(2k, 1, k^{-1})$. Is this a typo?

Comment: @Crostul Typo. Fixed.

Comment: $2k-a$ is a scalar, so it should be written $|2k-a|$. The double bar notation is used for the norm of a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method of tackling these sorts of problems. A sequence $x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ converges to $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ if an only if
$$\|x_n -v\| \to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$ (this is just the definition). Suppose that $x_n \to v$. The reverse triangle inequality states that
$$|\|x_n\|-\|v\|| \le \|x_n - v\|$$
for all $n$. The sandwich/squeeze theorem then implies that if $x_n \to v$ then $\|x_n \| \to \|v\|$ as $n\to\infty$. In particular if $x_n \to v$ then the sequence $\|x_n\|$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers ( and converges to $\|v\|$). We know that convergent sequences of real numbers are bounded.

Therefore, to show that $x_n$ does not converge in $\mathbb{R}^d$ it suffices to show that $\|x_n\|$ is not a bounded sequence of real numbers. Note that for your sequence
$$\|x_n\| = \left((2n)^2 + 1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/2} \ge 2n.$$
Hence $\|x_n\|$ is not bounded and so $x_n$ cannot converge in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

I will not go into detail on the solution you brought up, but rather comment on convergence of sequences $(x_n)\subset \mathbb R^d$.

I want to start with an easy lemma.

> Let $(x_n)=((x_{n,1},\ldots,x_{n,d}))\subset \mathbb R^d$ be a sequence and let $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_d)\in\mathbb R^d$.
> Then $x_n\to x$ if and only if the real sequences $x_{n,k}\to x_k$ for all $k=1,\ldots,d$.

You can find many proofs of this fact in the literature, so I will skip that part here. But let's summarize in words: to prove or disprove convergence of a sequence in $d$ dimensions, you can check convergence in each component separately.

And that's the key ingredient how to think of your example. So let $d=3$ and $x_n=(x_{n,1},x_{n,2},x_{n,3})=(2n,1,n^{-1}).$ While the sequences (x_{n,2}) and $(x_{n,3})$ converge (to 1 and 0, respectively), the sequences $(x_{n,1})=(2n)$ is obviously divergent. This directly shows, that the sequence $(x_n)$ is also divergent, by above lemma.